Localization of quasi-excellent rings are quasi-excellent?
If $R$ is a quasi-excellent ring, then is $R_{\mathfrak p}$ also quasi-excellent for every prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $R$ ?
I think Matsumura's commutative ring theory book says that localization of Excellent rings are again Excellent, but I do not know about quasi-excellence ...

Not very helpful: it is claimed without proof in [Tag 07QU].

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn: I see ... do you happen to know what happens to localization of $J$-$2$ rings? They still remain $J$-$2$ then?

Yes, localizations of quasi-excellent rings are quasi-excellent by (34.A) in Matsumura's Commutative algebra.
As you noted in the comments, the G-ring condition is already local, so the key point is that being J-2 localizes. This follows from characterization (3) of the J-2 property in [Matsumura, Theorem 73] (see also [EGAIV2, Théorème 6.12.4] and [Stacks, Tag 07PC].) The original reference is [Nagata 1959, Theorem 2(i)].

Thanks Takumi ... I'm guessing that what Nagata calls "formation of rings of quotients " is just arbitrary localization in our modern terminology?

@Alex Yes, that is correct. For example, this is the terminology Nagata uses in Chapter I, §6 of Local rings.
